# Ubuntu 16.0.4 live flash drive not working

Tags: 16.04, live-usb

I was attempting to make a live flashdrive for Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS 1 using a program called Rufus. It didn't work, so I tried Universal USB, LiLi, Active@ISO, PowerISO, and Live USB, with none of them working. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

P.S. I'm using a custom computer, here are the basic specifications:
Motherboard: MSI A68HI AC
Processor: AMD A8 7650K @ 3.3 Ghz

Comment: Please try the pre-installed Ubuntu __startup disk creator__. Check for it in __dash__.

Comment: Have you tried booting any of your Live drives in another computer. some USB installs work in one computer and not another. This could be due to Safe Boot, BIOS vs UEFI and other reasons, If it does boot in anotther computer it rules out bad USB, corrupt install, etc.

Comment: 1. Did you check with *md5sum* that the iso file was downloaded correctly? 2. Please describe with *details how the boot fails*. 3. Is Windows installed? 4. Is the computer booting in UEFI mode or BIOS mode? Please specify the graphics card/chip! 5. Do you want to use the flash drive to run the computer, or 'only' to install Ubuntu into another drive?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Yes, and it hasn't worked

Comment: @sudodus I just checked the md5 checksum and it's not correct

Comment: 1. Use the torrent method to get the file. It has a built-in check of the md5sum. 2. If your internet service provider does not allow torrents, try to download the iso file again, and hope you have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

Mkusb should work if anything will. problem is it is Linux only ... except:

There is now an experimental mkusb image that can be installed to USB using Windows Image Writer.

See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&p=13580365#post13580365
The download is under 300MB.

The finished USB contains a mini Debian OS with mkusb and guidus and not much else installed.

The drive can be used to make a sophisticated persistent Flash drive that works with UEFI and BIOS.

You can alternately boot the Ubuntu Live optical disk, install mkusb or guidus and use that to make a persistent flash drive.

Comment: The reason that I wanted a bootable flash drive was because my DVD Rewriter wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ubuntu's pre-installed *startup disk creator*.
Steps:

1. download the __ISO__image
2. get a good working usb flash storage
3. launch startup disk creator from dash
4. insert usb flash storage
5. locate the downloaded **ISO** image
6. click *make startup disk*

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not currently using Ubuntu

Comment: On what system are you trying to make the flash drive ?

Comment: I'm using a latitude E6500 with windows 7 64 bit